# Manipulating Dataframes in different sub directories

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, glob, python-os

I have many subdirecotries in which I have unique datasets. I want to do some manipulations on this df individually. Something like: Access to each subdirectory, do manipulation, go to next directory and do the same. For illustrative purposes I can provide the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os 


os.mkdir('folder1')

d = {'column1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'column2': [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], 'column3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
test_a  = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
test_a.to_csv('folder1/test_a.csv')

os.mkdir('folder2')
g = {'column1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'column2': [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], 'column3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
test_b = pd.DataFrame(data=g)
test_b.to_csv('folder2/test_b.csv')
```

The code above creates the subdirectories and then saves example df in this subdirectory.

Let's say I want to achieve the following:

Grouby (count) each dataset in each folder by column1, and save it in the corresponding subdirectory as a separate data frame. Better to call each data frame by the starting letters (test in this case), rather than its extension (csv).

I can write the general function on how to grouby the datasets, but I don't know how to access each subdirectory. (probably using the for loop and os/glob package).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a folder like folder1, you want to create a subdirectory like folder1/subfolder1 to save your dataframe?

Comment: No, I want to manipulate data frames in each directory (folder1 and folder2) separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pathlib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

# directory where data files are stored
data_dir = pathlib.Path('data')

for csvfile in data_dir.glob('**/*.csv'):
    print(f"Processing '{csvfile.name}' in '{csvfile.parent}'")
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    # do stuff here
    out = df.groupby('column1').mean()  # mean or whatever you want
    out.to_csv(csvfile.parent / f"{csvfile.stem}_grp.csv")
    print(f"Saved as '{csvfile.stem}_grp.csv' in '{csvfile.parent}'")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Processing 'test_a.csv' in 'data/folder1'
Saved as 'test_a_grp.csv' in 'data/folder1'

Processing 'test_b.csv' in 'data/folder2'
Saved as 'test_b_grp.csv' in 'data/folder2'
```

Directory tree:

```
data
├── folder1
│   ├── test_a.csv
│   └── test_a_grp.csv
└── folder2
    ├── test_b.csv
    └── test_b_grp.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works! One additional question. If you want to search df based on the starting characters how would you specify it in `glob` code.? Now it only takes df based on csv extension. What I also want additionally is to take df based on "test" word.

Comment: You can try something like that: `data_dir.glob('**/test_*.csv')`